# Should Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window) work with any window handle?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modal-dialog, bho

When using `System.Windows.Forms.ShowDialog(IWin32Window)`, should I be able to pass in an `IWin32Window` representing any window handle and have it be modal with respect to that window?

As part of an Internet Explorer 7 extension I'm trying to open a window modal with respect to an Internet Explorer tab. It's not the currently selected tab, but I can get the hwnd of the tab OK. However, when I pass this to ShowDialog my Form is shown, but it's not modal with respect to anything: I can still do things in Internet Explorer, including in the tab that's supposed to be the owner. My form is shown floating above the Internet Explorer windows and it stays on top, so it's not like it's just opened as a normal form, but it's not correctly modal.

Using [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), I can find my form and it's owner handle is correctly set.

Does this mean that something has gone wrong, or I'm doing something wrong? How do I make my form correctly modal?

FYI, I'm using this wrapper class to create an `IWin32Window` from a `hwnd` (thanks [Ryan!](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/03/23/465.aspx)):

```
/// <summary>
/// Wrapper class so that we can return an IWin32Window given a hwnd
/// </summary>
public class WindowWrapper : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
{
    public WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
    {
        _hwnd = handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { return _hwnd; }
    }

    private IntPtr _hwnd;
}
```

UPDATE: Using Internet Explorer 7 & .NET 2.0

UPDATE: Playing around some more with Spy++ and the handles it exposes, I find that if I use a different `hwnd` then I can make my window modal to the tab:

I was using the tab's `hwnd` as suggested by the [IWebBrowser2.HWND doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752126(VS.85).aspx), which in Spy++ appears as class `TabWindowClass`. It has a child of class `Shell DocObject View`, which has a child of Internet_Explorer_Server. If I use the `hwnd` of the `Internet Explorer_Server` then it works correctly, for example, when I click with the mouse on other tabs, Internet Explorer reacts normally. When I click with the mouse on the tab of interest, it plays the windows d'oh sound and doesn't do anything.

I don't yet know how to programatically get the Internet_Explorer_Server `hwnd`, but it should be possible.

Also, for what it's worth, while playing with other window handles I was generally able to make my form modal to other applications and dialogs. So I guess the answer to my question is 'many but not all handles'... possibly it depends on the application?

UPDATE: Another side-note: The original reason I wanted to make my form modal to the tab instead of the whole window is that when opening a `MessageBox` from my form, passing the form as owner, the `MessageBox` would not always open on top of my form. If a new Internet Explorer tab had just been opened but wasn't active then the `MessageBox` would be hidden and that tab would start flashing. However, since Internet Explorer was disabled with my form opened modal it wasn't possible to switch to that tab, so Internet Explorer would be frozen. I thought that opening my form modal to the tab would solve this, but I've found another solution is to avoid using `MessageBox`: if I use a second form and `ShowDialog(this)` from my first form then the second form correctly opens to the front. So it seems that `Form.ShowDialog()` works better than `MessageBox.Show()` in some cases. More discussion in *[Problems with modal dialogs and messageboxes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/df0fe7f2-0153-47d9-b18f-266d57ab7909)*.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct.  The problem you are likely running into though is that IE has a threading model related to its tabs.  I don't know the exact details but the short version is that each tab can and likely is running on a different thread than other tabs.

The Modal'ness of a dialog is specific to the thread where the dialog is running.  UI on other threads will be unaffected by a model dialog on another thread.  It's entirely possible you are able to access tabs which are running on a different thread for this reason.

Comment: I don't think what you say about the threading is quite correct. If I use the hwnd of say a Notepad window then it works fine. Unless it's different between threads in the same process & threads in a different process. Looks to me like each window does something clever to work out if it's locked.

Comment: @Rory, that may be the case but what I've said about threads is correct.  A modal dialog on one thread will not affect UI in another trhead.

Answer (score 5):

ShowDialog() does two important things.  It starts pumping a message loop so it acts modally to the calling code.  And it disables any other windows in the application with a EnableWindow(false) API call.  The latter is what is not happening in your case.  Not entirely surprising, considering that the window that needs to be disabled is not a WF window.

You may need to call EnableWindow() yourself.  Be sure to re-enable it in before the dialog closes or Windows will go hunting for another app's window to give the focus to.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more concise version of Ryan/Rory's WindowWrapper code:

```
internal class WindowWrapper : IWin32Window
{
    public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }
    public WindowWrapper(IntPtr hwnd) { Handle = hwnd; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this from an IE extension, but I have a hunch that IE may not "respect" a Win32-style modal window the same way it does a modal window raised from Javascript using `window.open().`

Have you tested this code against something other than IE, just to confirm it works the way it should for other applications?

Answer (score 0):

here is a build in solution in .NET:

public static NativeWindow FromHandle(IntPtr handle)