# Using Windows functions to make a window modal

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, modal-dialog

I m using c# and I want to make a window a modal one and I want to use methods from Windows API for that.
The SetWindowPos function can make a window a top most one, but I couldn t find a way to make it modal...

Is there a way to do so with SetWindowPos or if not, is there any other windows function to do so?

Comment: If you don't **need** to use Windows APIs for this sort of thing, don't do it. Otherwise you might as well not be developing on the .NET Framework.

Comment: I want to make modal the window created by calling GetSaveFileName windows function

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the already existing managed ways of doing this? Like `Form.ShowDialog()` for instance?

Comment: Coz I have customized the savefiledialog using HookProc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that your question is tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), you have the entire .NET Framework at your disposal, which provides built-in functionality for displaying windows (forms) as modal dialogs. There's no reason you should have to call functions from the Windows API to do this.

In general, the only reason to P/Invoke functions from the Windows API is to use features that were not already exposed through managed code. The average application will have to do this only rarely, and basic use cases like showing a modal dialog certainly does not require it.

The way to do this in C# (or any .NET language) is to change the way you show the form in question. Instead of calling the `Form.Show` method, you should use the [**`Form.ShowDialog`** method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx).

There are two overloads available. The [first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) accepts no parameters and sets the owner of the dialog box to the currently active window. The [second](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx) accepts a single parameter that specifies the window that will own this dialog.

The [`Form.Modal` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.modal.aspx) provides a quick way of checking to see whether or not the form is displayed modally. As the documentation notes, however, it is read-only. The only way to display a form modally is to call the `ShowDialog` method, as discussed above.

As far as a Windows API solution, there isn't any such function that you can call. A window cannot be transformed into a modal dialog after it has been created. You have to display it that way initially. In a Win32 application, you do that by calling the [`DialogBox` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645452.aspx) (as opposed to [`CreateDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645434.aspx)).

MFC shows a modal dialog using the [`CDialog::DoModal` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5.aspx), but it doesn't truly show a modal dialog. Instead, it uses a hack to create a *pseudo* (or simulated) modal dialog that involves disabling the owner window, running its own message loop inside the `DoModal` method, and waiting for a pre-defined series of events that causes the modal loop to exit gracefully. I **do not** recommend doing this in your own application. It's simply not necessary, and it's too easy to get wrong. There are/were enough bugs in the MFC approach, and that team had the full knowledge of the Win32 internals at its disposal.

The `ShowDialog` method in WinForms works on a model very similar to that of MFC. Hans's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581855/should-form-showdialogiwin32window-work-with-any-window-handle/582241#582241) provides additional information. Do note that if you're going to implement your own modal dialog loop, you need to remember to re-enable the 
owner window *first*, and then destroy the modal dialog. If you don't do this in the correct order, you'll end up with the wrong window having the focus. Microsoft's Raymond Chen posted a blog entry about this: [The correct order for disabling and enabling windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040227-00/?p=40463).

---

**EDIT:** Added more information, based on comments from asker.

I'm not sure why you need the wrapper you've created to customize the save dialog to be a `UserControl`. It's not a control, the user isn't going to interact with it on your form. You're only going to show it from your code. Thus, I think the better option would be to create a new class, call it something like `SaveDialogHelper`, and expose a static method called `ShowSaveDialog` or something like that. For example:

```
public static class SaveDialogHelper
{
    public string ShowSaveDialog(IWin32Window owner)
    {
        // Fill the OPENFILENAME struct, and do any necessary customizations
        // ...

        // Show the save dialog
        // ...

        // Return the path that was selected by the user
        // ...
    }
}
```

Notice that the `ShowSaveDialog` function accepts a single parameter (`owner`) of type [`IWin32Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.iwin32window.aspx), just like the `ShowDialog` method(s) in the .NET Framework. When you call that function, just specify the form that you want to own the dialog:

```
SaveDialogHelper.ShowSaveDialog(this);
```

And inside the function, you can extract the window handle (`hwnd` in Win32 terminology) using the [`Handle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.iwin32window.handle.aspx), and set the `hwndOwner` member of the `OPENFILENAME` structure accordingly:

```
hwndOwner = owner.Handle;
```

Comment: Actually as I have customized my savefiledialog, I have implemented the ShowDialog method on my own, and inside that, I m calling GetSaveFileName to createt the savefiledialog. So I want to add that modal feature in my ShowDialog method.. any answer???

Comment: @dia: I don't understand why you have re-implemented the `ShowDialog` method on your own. Do you mean that you've created a separate form you call *instead* of `SaveFileDialog`, and that *that* form is instead responsible for calling/displaying the save dialog? The Windows API function `GetSaveFileName` takes an `OPENFILENAME` structure as a parameter, one of the members of which is `hwndOwner`. If you specify the correct window handle here, it will automatically display the dialog modally with that window as its owner.

Comment: @dia: Use that to specify the handle to your *main* window, not the one that wraps the call to `GetSaveFileName`. I suspect you're *currently* passing that window's handle, so the function is doing the right thing and disabling that window. Except that, you don't care if that window is disabled.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct!!! Thanks a lot for that! I had to customize the savefile dialog in order to add some checkboxes for it... So this I m implementing a new user control. But can you pls explain me a way of identifying that form??? One way I thought is to send the handle of the mainform when the object to the user control is created...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!! It works well!!! I also followed this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163435/c-method-caller . Both methods work well... Thank you very much again...

Comment: @dia: You certainly could do that, but remember that there is a (potentially) significant cost associated with using Reflection. Since the caller should always know which form they want to disable, it's faster and simpler to specify it as a parameter. It also makes it clearer what the function does, which window will be disabled, and prevents any potential problems where the wrong window is disabled if you call the function from a background thread or a different form (like when you implement auto-save functionality in your app!). Anyway, you're welcome. Glad you were able to get this to work.

Comment: Yeah, that s true, so I feel it s better to use the parameter... Thank you loads for great advices

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it modal if it was not upon creation. But you can achieve similar effect by disabling its <strike>parent</strike> owner.

Comment: More accurately, you would be disabling its *owner*. The difference between parent windows and owner windows is not always very clear in the documentation, although it's an important one. Raymond Chen provides more information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/15/9978691.aspx).

Comment: Oops. I stand corrected. Owner is what I actually meant: A modal window obviously doesn't have a parent.